# Dual stack IPv4/IPv6 on 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS kills website user experience, unclear how or why

Tags: networking, internet, performance, connection, ipv6

I've been running IPv6 enabled (dual stack) hosts for years. Ubuntu back to at least 16.04, maybe 14.04 and to present day. I figured this was settled technology and there were no gotchas in our implementation.

Decided to enable IPv6 dual stack on some busy (>1Gb/s public facing, internet load, global) hosts. Just added the IP6 address (fixed, not dynamic) to netplan, ip6 gateway, and added the AAAA record to DNS. Nothing else. Didn't even reboot, just applied.

My UFW rules are all enabled for dual stack like every other host I've ever had running as dual stack. The relevant sysctl's are default which is enabled.

Almost immediately, I saw 10x increase in failed connection attempts in netstat -s (see image). I reviewed this very thorough article: https://serverfault.com/questions/885403/linux-tracking-the-source-of-netstat-s-failed-connection-attempts and didn't get any closer to a cause. No customers complained, and the number went from say 1 per 1000 to 1 per 100s. Successful IPv6 connections were happening (about 1% average, 7-8% peak)

It (connection fails) was very steady, and figured if it was a real issue, customers or our monitoring would detect a problem. No such luck. This counter is only supposed to increment on outbound connections, these servers send a few thousand emails per day to report what their progress to their users all over the world, so I figured this was the mail server getting rejected on IPv6 in various places... annoying, but not an issue.

Over the next 5 days before taking action on the impacted hosts... traffic levels declined and moreover, stopped growing. The 1 per 100 connection thing seemed to be impacting a lot of customers, even though no one complained.

Without making any other changes, simply removing the IPv6 AAAA entry from the DNS of the impacted services and within hours the fails dropped by a factor of 10 and usage levels are growing back to normal. Obviously this eliminates the mail question because mail is still being delivered over IPv4 and IPv6. This server makes no out-of-network connections except DNS/mail and all internal connections are IPv4 -- (it uses NFS and an internal object store over https). The only public facing service is Apache2 and HTTP/2 is enabled. We are tracking latest-stable for Apache2 not the Ubuntu general release version.

I'm scratching my head as to what related to the receiving connection use of IPv6 could be impacting users and only have the netstat to go on which could totally be some kind of lark.

There are no illustrative apache2 logs to indicate any sort of connection problem on IPv4 or IPv6.

Observations:

Occurs on both 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS

Occurs on multiple disparate VMs running different sites on different hypervisors.

Leaving the IPv6 configuration live, but not advertising it in DNS keeps the issue from occurring.

No syslog or apache2 logs to document any issue.

Happens on multiple versions of Apache2.

Physical hardware is HP DL380 or DL360, connections are all 10G ethernet.

VMs are in KVM/libvirt using bridges on VLANs through the host OS. Both the host OS and the VM are Ubuntu, generally 18.04 LTS but other combinations may exist.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

[Munin Graph of increased failed connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a6bQ.png)